# Router Events and preloader without state in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

I am trying to convert this code to not use state as I have heard using setState in _app.js is not recommended and leads to errors. I can't quite figure out how to do it. Any help would be awesome.
Thanks

```
export default class BookingApp extends App {

.....

componentDidMount() {

    Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true })
    })

    Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false })
    })

    Router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false })
    })
}
return (
....
{this.state.isLoading && (
    <div>
        <Loader />
    </div>
)}
...Other Content
```

Comment: You could try moving the entire Loader component including the state, conditionals and the logic of componentDidMount into another component and use the final "Loader" component above ....Other Content. Currently you're only inserting the UI loader element. Move the logic part to the Loader component

Comment: I both love and hate how easy that was. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped. I have added it as an answer below with a hooks implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have only made the UI aspect of the `Loader` into a separate component.

Move the entire logic into the seperate `Loader` component instead of the _app.js file.

Below is a hooks implementation of the `Loader` component. It can be done using class components too.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Loader = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
    });

    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    });

    router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {
        isLoading && (
          <LoaderUIComponentComesHere />
        )
      }
    </>
  );
};

export default Loader;
```